# My website on Chrome 77 doesn't load any data, but it works fine on Chrome 76

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, dompurify, trusted-types

What's worse, is that my tests pass using Chrome 77 with Chromedriver 77 (the tests pass, the data is loaded in the webpages, etc.).  It's only if I manually pull up a Chrome 77 browser and test it that it fails.

Here's basically what my code is doing:

```js
// Get the query parameter "operation" from the URL
let match = new RegExp("[?&]operation=([^&]*)").exec(window.location.search);
let param = match && decodeURIComponent(match[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));

// Sanitize the URL from XSS Injection
let param = param ? window.DOMPurify.sanitize(param) : param;

if(param === "View") {
    // Load data from the server
}
```

The problem is that in Chrome 77 `param === "View"` is false!  But it's not false when using Chrome 77 on it's own.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out!  The problem is the Chrome 77 turns on the TrustedTypes API by default.  But it's turned off if Chrome 77 is started through Chromedriver, which is a pretty [nasty bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=3121).

The fix to get Chrome 77 / Chromedriver 77 to fail like it does when you manually hit the page is to enable this chrome feature:

```
--enable-blink-features=TrustedDOMTypes
```

You'd put it in the same place you see `--no-sandbox` or `--disable-infobars`.

Great!  Now your tests fail as they should. Next, to fix the error, change this line:

```
// Sanitize the URL from XSS Injection
let param = param ? window.DOMPurify.sanitize(param) : param;
```

To this instead:

```
// Sanitize the URL from XSS Injection
let param = param ? (window.DOMPurify.sanitize(param) || "").toString() : param;
```

The `toString()` is the most important part. A TrustedType object is being returned now, instead of a String.